Jodit-react: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'document')
I am trying to use jodit-react, I used the same config outlined in this article
My ReactJs component is intuitively like below
<JoditEditor
  ref={editor}
  value={state.content}
  config={config}
  onChange={handleContentChange}
/>

I am seeing this error when I reach the related page:
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'document')
I appreciate your assistance
I tried adding useMemo to the change handler like below, expecting the error to go away, but no luck
const handleContentChange = useMemo((contentHtml) => {
    setState((p) => ({
      ...p,
      content: contentHtml,
    }));
  }, []);


I was able to resolve it by using useMemo on the definition of the config object.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
